# asp:listbox validation

Tags: asp.net

I have two asp:ListBox. The ID's are Authors and AuthorsSelected. Authors listbox is loaded with all  the authors and AuthorsSelected is empty at first. Using  Javascript code, I am moving items from Authors to AuthorsSelected.

Now, before submitting the form, I want to verify that AuthorsSelected listbox is not empty. I tried asp:RequiredFieldValidator and it's not workijng and giving error message.

Please let me know how to validate the AuthorsSelected listbox and make sure it's not empty before submitting the form. Thanks.

Comment: "it's not working and giving error message" - *what* error message? It's there for a reason :)

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP._admin_addbook_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Requiredfieldvalidator3' and no extension method 'Requiredfieldvalidator3' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP._admin_addbook_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Line 456:            #line default
Line 457:            #line hidden
Line 458:            this.Requiredfieldvalidator3 = @__ctrl;
Line 459:            @__ctrl.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this);
Line 460:

Comment: Hi, please mark the code as the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this very simple example:

```
   <p>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function validateListbox() {
            var listbox = document.getElementById("<%= ListBox1.ClientID  %>");

            if (listbox.length == 0)
                alert("no items!");

            return (listbox.length > 0);

        }        
    </script>


    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>

</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="BtnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return validateListbox()" />
</p>
```

Please note ListBox1.ClientID usage; I use it in order to reference my listbox in JavaScript.

Comment: Hello Mr. Sander,
The code worked perfect. Thanks for your help.